# Get json data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, http

I am trying to get a json array of ints from a server by sending the server a get request. When I run the code below the server receives the request. How can I print the data the server sends back?  The second alert() doesn't show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("READyS");

$("button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Data/", function (data) {
      alert("data recieved");
  });
});
```

});

Comment: But in  http://localhost:8080/Data/ ... /Data/ seem to be one directory not a json file

Comment: Check your Network tab in Developer Tools and see why the request is  failing to receive a response.

Comment: @FreemanLambda= I get this No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: Then you need to configure your server to allow CORS requests from your client-side domain. Google: "how to enable CORS for <your-server-technology>"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can use this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.get( "http://localhost:8080/Data/" )
     .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
   });
});
```

Obs.: Please be more specific about what button is.

If still don't work, paste your html here

Comment: This is exactly what OP is doing. Please read the comments on the question and you will see that OP is not receiving a response at all, because their server cannot serve CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function passed to success state of the AJAX request. This way you're using the async nature of the request, which doesn't block the browser call stack while it's waiting for requested data and You're getting the result printed to the page. This is just a single `p` element that has all the request's information inside of it, so it will work if it's just a string. If it's an array of objects or something like that then you can create a `map` function with `printData` function inside it to loop through all of the downloaded objects.

```
function printData(passedData) {
  jQuery('<p/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    text: passedData
  }).appendTo('body');
}

function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/Data/",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
    }
  });
}

testAjax(printData);
```